# Using GAE Channel's from a TaskQueue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, channel-api

I have been trying for some days to use the `channel.send_message` API in GAE (via Python) to send a message to a client when a TaskQueue process has finished. It just WON'T work.

I can use send_message from another request and it works fine and is received. But nothing when send_message is called from a TaskQueue.
 I've tried this both locally and deployed to GAE full. Is this not a supported scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me. Make sure you are publishing using the same client key `keyid` in both

```
channel.send_message(keyid,message_string)
```

and

```
token = channel.create_channel(keyid)
```

i.e. make sure you are NOT using `token` as the first parameter in `send_message()`.

I would log (using `logging.info()`) the `keyid` (and `token`) everywhere you use it in the python code and `console.log()` the `token` in the javascript code to make sure they all match where they should.